# Storing a lot of numeric data in database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, bigdata

I have following issue. I need to store lot of numeric (float) data in the database which quite often repeat (90% are the same).

So I am looking for a solution/technology how to store them and save space and speed. We are talking about 100MB data a day (storing in naive way - store all of them).

Now I store them in PostgreSQL and do some tricks to save space/time.

But still with all of the tricks, it is only SQL database and I think there is a better tool/technology.

Do you have some tips for technologies/other databases, principles to use? Using Python(Django) and PostgreSQL.

edit: Why/usage: I want to have it in a database because I need to show these data in plots/tables in a web app (thats why the django). So I need to have these data easy accessible by query

```
E.g.
days>| I | II | III | IV | V ...
 A   | 1 |  1 |  1  |  1 | 1 ...
 B   | 2 |  2 |  5  |  5 | 5 ...
 C   | 3 |  3 |  3  |  3 | 7 ...
 D   | 4 |  4 |  4  |  4 | 8 ...
.
.
.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Developing your own data compression and decompression tool may help in this case, You may optimise the tool to store only relevant changes in the data, it may be visualised as saving only the changes, which would improve efficiency by 60-90 %

Comment: There are extensions for column stores in postgres available. Maybe worth a view.

Comment: 100MB i not a lot at all. And the solution will depends on how you want to use that, if you just want to store it than gziped text file is the best solution.

Comment: sorry, I should explain. I want to have it in a database because I need to show these data in plots/tables in a web app (thats why the django). So I need to have these data easy accessible by query. But thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Are entire rows the same, or just individual values?

Comment: @Travis it can repeat but it doesnt have to. E.g. value for A repeats every day (in each dataset) but for B it can change. Now as I can see the "code" it can be a little bit problematic to understand, sorry. Everyday (I, II, III...) I insert dataset ( like A=1, B=2, C=3, D=8...)

Comment: You need to post your actual data structure and the queries you need to run.

Comment: Judging purely on the information you have provided, this is probably not worth the effort. It's pretty hard to normalize this any further if you are lucky you would be saving 16 bits per record.

Comment: What you really want for this is a column store to benefit from vertical compression. That said, 100MB is pretty small.